# Java/Eclipse - Resolving IOException when using BufferedReader outside of main method

Tags: java, error-handling, bufferedreader, ioexception

I am currently in the process of a creating a program that gets a suffix ("ing", "er" etc.) from a user and then attaches that suffix to list of words from an input file. The problem is that I am using a buffered reader to get the suffix the user wants to use, but I keep getting an error (Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed) 
when I compile. You will notice below that I do not close the buffered reader anywhere, because that is when I get the error (Where should I close it?) I simply want to the take the user's input and set it as a string variable to be used within the class. Any suggestions??

```
public static String GetSuffix (String psSingular1) throws IOException {

    //Use BufferedReader to get suffix
    BufferedReader brGetSuffix = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    //Prompt the user for a suffix
    System.out.println("Please insert a suffix that you would like add to the words (ex. er, ing, ance,etc.)");

    //Set a string to the user entered suffix
    String sUserSuffix = brGetSuffix.readLine();

    //Initialize sSuffix
    String sSuffix = "";

    //Each string represents the last characters of the word from the input file
    String sLast1 = psSingular1.toLowerCase().substring(psSingular1.length()-1, psSingular1.length());


    String s2ndLast = psSingular1.toLowerCase().substring(psSingular1.length()-2, psSingular1.length()-1);

    //This string represents the last letter of the word
    String sLastLetter = psSingular1.toLowerCase().substring(psSingular1.length()-1, psSingular1.length());

    //This string represents a double vowel. It will be used in a word like "keep"
    String sDoubleVowel = psSingular1.toLowerCase().substring(psSingular1.length()-3, psSingular1.length()-1);

    //This String will represent the first character of the users suffix which will be needed to determine how the suffix is added to the word
    String s1stSuffix = sUserSuffix.toLowerCase().substring(0, 0);


    //If the word ends in 2 vowels and a consonant the suffix is added
    if (bIsVowel(sDoubleVowel) && !bIsVowel(sLast1)){

        sSuffix = psSingular1 + sUserSuffix;
    }


        //Checks if psSingular1 ends in a consonant and y, changes the y to i and adds a suffix.
        else if (sLast1.equals("y") && !bIsVowel(s2ndLast)){

        //Drop the "y" add "ies"
        sSuffix = psSingular1.substring(0, psSingular1.length()-1) + "i" + sUserSuffix;
        }

        //Checks if psSingular1 ends in a vowel and y
        else if (sLast1.equals("y") && bIsVowel(s2ndLast)){

            sSuffix = psSingular1 + sUserSuffix;
        }

        //Checks if psSingular1 ends in e and if the suffix starts with a vowel
        else if (sLast1.equals("e") && bIsVowel(s1stSuffix)){

            sSuffix = psSingular1.substring(0, psSingular1.length()) + sUserSuffix;
        }

        //Checks if psSingular1 ends in e and if the suffix starts with a consonant
        else if (sLast1.equals("e") && !bIsVowel(s1stSuffix)){

            sSuffix = psSingular1 + sUserSuffix;
        }

        //Checks if the word ends in two consonants
        else if (!bIsVowel(s2ndLast) && !bIsVowel(sLast1)){

            sSuffix = psSingular1 + sUserSuffix;

        }

        //If the the word ends in a vowel and a consonant the last letter is doubled and the suffix is added
        else if (bIsVowel(s1stSuffix) && bIsVowel(s2ndLast) && !bIsVowel(sLast1)){


            sSuffix = psSingular1 + sLastLetter + sUserSuffix;
        }

        //Add the suffix
        else {

            sSuffix = psSingular1 + sUserSuffix;

        }


    return sSuffix;

}
```

Comment: Could you just try with:
`BufferedReader brGetSuffix = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new CloseShieldInputStream(System.in)));` and tell us if it still doesn't work?

Comment: @ccjmne Copy and pasted exactly what you have and I am getting an error under CloseShieldInputStream. Is it part of a class that may need to get imported?

Comment: Oops... sorry, you're right... it's from `org.apache.commons.io.input`. Actually, maybe you could just use `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);` then `String sUserSuffix = scanner.nextLine();`. If you're just getting a few caracters from an user input, you may not need to use a BufferedReader. I know it doesn't answer your question but maybe at least you could go on :)

Comment: @ccjmne I decided to go with the scanner and I am able to compile, but I am now getting the error: (Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found). I did input something so I don't understand why there is "no line found". I also closed the scanner, any thoughts?

Comment: What about: `if scanner.hasNextLine() { sUserSuffix = scanner.nextLine() }` It has to work at one point seriously...

Comment: Well, it's driving me crazy. Could I please have your complete code? My personal e-mail address is available on my profile.

Comment: @ccjmne Okay, I tried the while loop you suggested got another error upon closing the scanner. I will try the if and I will email the whole program. This is an extra credit portion of my final for computer science class. It is due at 12, so if you don't get something by then don't worry about it.

Comment: Thank you :) And don't worry, it's my pleasure. I just moved in a new city, I still don't have so many acquaintances around here and my laptop cannot run any game - plus I have really low internet debit. So I'm just basically doing the only thing I've left: goofing around with Eclipse :')

Comment: @ccjmne I sent the email, let me know if you get it

Comment: @ccjmne Okay, Good news. The if statement worked. It compiled and added the suffix to the first word in the list of words, but not the rest. May be an issue of where I am closing the scanner.

Comment: I got your mail and gave you an answer. I'm pretty sure we figured out what is wrong exactly in your code, but it will actually take more than one single line replacement for it to work :) Please kindly let me know when you get it to work so we can post an answer and accept this so everyone can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like we're missing some code (where is psSingular1 coming from?), but maybe try closing the buffered reader somewhere and see if it helps. Once you're done adding input to the reader, you can close it. It could even be right before the return statement.

Comment: `psSingular1` comes as an argument of his function. I think he gave us the the amount of code that is relevant (but since something is clearly wrong, maybe the actual closing of the stream is done somewhere else).

Comment: AH thank you. That was really silly of me -- I overlooked it somehow. I don't think the stream closing is done elsewhere, since the stream is a local object, and the entire method seems to be posted.

Comment: PsSingular comes from the string parameter at the beginning of the class.I dont think it is relevant to the error I mentioned. I have tried closing buffered reader in several different areas, but as I mentioned I keep getting the same error.

Comment: You're not trying to close the underlying Stream either, by any chance? `System.in.close()` anywhere?